# How to insert attribute in a selected feature from active layer (PyQGIS)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I want to update some fields from a selected feature in an edit session with some values provided by a form made in QtDesigner. The fields have indexes 0 and 2.

Tried so far:

```
from edit_Form import Ui_EditForm

class editForm(QtGui.QDialog):
 def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_EditForm()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)

 def accept(self):

     for i in iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures():
        fid = i.id()
        provider = iface.activeLayer().dataProvider()
        name = iface.activeLayer().fieldNameIndex("NAME")
        siruta = iface.activeLayer().fieldNameIndex("SIRUTA")
        textNAME = self.ui.NAME.text()
        textSIRUTA = self.ui.SIRUTA.text()
        i.setAttribute(0,self.ui.NAME.text() )
        i.setAttribute(2,self.ui.SIRUTA.text())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
def accept(self):

 for i in iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures():
    fid = i.id()
    provider = iface.activeLayer().dataProvider()
    name = iface.activeLayer().fieldNameIndex("NAME")
    siruta = iface.activeLayer().fieldNameIndex("SIRUTA")
    textNAME = self.ui.NAME.text()
    textSIRUTA = self.ui.SIRUTA.text()
    iface.activeLayer().changeAttributeValue(fid,name,textNAME)
    iface.activeLayer().changeAttributeValue(fid,siruta,textSIRUTA)
    iface.activeLayer().commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use QGIS 2.0+ then:

```
def accept(self):
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    layer.startEditing()
    textNAME = self.ui.NAME.text()
    textSIRUTA = self.ui.SIRUTA.text()
    for i in layer.selectedFeatures():
        i["NAME"] = textNAME
        i["SIRUTA"] = textSIRUTA
    layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: I use Qgis 2.12.3 Lyon, i run the loop in Python Console, but no result. After running: iface.activeLayer().commitChanges(), I get "True" bollean, without no effects in attribute table.

Comment: I forget to change layer to your situation. I've edited my answer